# Regular expression to accept decimal numbers between 0 to 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

My requirement is a regular expression it accepts decimal values between 0 to 100 (like 1,2,3,....,99, 0.1,0.2,0.3,.....,99.9, 0.01,0.02,0.03,.....,99.99, 00.01 to 99.99). I found one solution

```
/^(?!0?0\.00$)\d{1,2}\.\d{2}$/
```

but it accepts only decimal values like 00.01 to 99.99.

Comment: Won't rounding off your number, and comparing it with 0 and 100 be easier?

Comment: Try this Regex (100)|[1-9]\d?

Comment: I won't do it with regex.

Comment: @Kent I thought he is looking for a Regex

Comment: @CrazyMac sure, he is asking for it. However he is asking how to hit a nail with a screw driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
^(?!0+(?:\.0+)?$)\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^           : begining of string
  (?!       : negative lookahead, assumes there is no:
    0+      : 1 or more zero
    (?:     : non capture group
      \.0+  : a dot then 1 or more zeros
    )?$     : end of group, optional, until end of string
  )         : end of lookahead
  \d?\d     : 1 or 2 digit
  (?:       : non capture group
    \.\d\d? : a dot followed by 1 or 2 digit
  )?        : end of group, optional
$           : end of string
```

Comment: Looks promising or to disallow eg `01` a similar one: [`^(?!0+\d?[.0]*$)\d\d?(?:\.\d\d?)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/4qM1yG/2)

Comment: @Java4you: You're welcome, glad it helps. Feel free to mark the answer as accepted: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Thanks it is working as expected. Once more thing, how can I change the regular expression to allow 0, 0.0, 0.00, 00. Please update the regular expression and share it to me..

Comment: @Java4you: Remove the negative lookahead. The regex will be: `^\d?\d(?:\.\d\d?)?$`

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:
`^(100|([0-9][0-9]?(\.[0-9]+)?))$`

First handle the outer case of the 100 number, then tend to the remaining combinations.

Make sure to escape the backward slash when using this in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression.

```
/^(\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,2})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(100|([0-9][0-9]?(\.\d{1,2})?))/
```

this will return the decimal number between 0 to 100 with match 2 digits and optional two decimal.
**e.g. out put would be like one of these**

```
3
33
33.3
33.33
```